# How to check if there is an object on a specific day in django?

Tags: django, datetime, django-views, timedelta

My aim is to check if there is an object created on the specific day, and if, to add a number to the list. However, I seem to do it totally wrong.

```
def week_days_activity(self):

    has = list()

    if ( User_activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1))):
       has.append(1)  
    else :
       has.append(0)

    if ( User_activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.now() -timedelta(days=2))):
       has.append(2) 
    else :
       has.append(0)
    if ( User_activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.now() -timedelta(days=3))):
       has.append(3)
    else :
       has.append(0)
    return has
```

timestamp is:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

I've searching around stackoverflow and the answers seem to round around these scheme but I probably don't get something.

So please help. Thanks :)

Comment: how is `timestamp` defined ?

Comment: it's a DateTimeField, I edited the question to include it.

Comment: Use `.count()`, it's more efficient.

Comment: What's "wrong" exactly?

Comment: Well, the list I get with this code has all of the numbers, 1,2 and 3. But I have objects just from today. Something is wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: You are only setting `has`. Where are you seeing the objects ?

Comment: The list I should get should be 1,0,0.

Comment: You need to use the range operator to get that. You are getting everything after the day. Not for the specific day. Hence the issue.

Comment: @karthikr I don't need to see the objects, I just want to check if one exists. `objects = User_activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7))` - this returns all the objects in the last 7 days I guess, because as I add new, new pop up. So the code above just for checking if the object exist should be fine.

Comment: @karthikr can you show me an example of the usage of the range operator here?

Comment: sure. Just check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def week_days_activity(self):

    has = []
    today = datetime.now().today()
    1_day_ago = today - timedelta(days=1)
    2_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=2)
    3_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=3)


    qs = User_activity.objects

    if qs.filter(timestamp__gte = 1_day_ago).count():
        has.append(1)
    else :
       has.append(0)

    if qs.filter(timestamp__range= (2_days_ago, 1_day_ago)).count():
       has.append(2)  
    else :
       has.append(0)

    if qs.filter(timestamp__range= (3_days_ago, 2_days_ago)).count():
       has.append(3)  
    else :
       has.append(0)

    return has
```

Read more about [`__range` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)

A slightly more readable approach (IMO):

```
has = [0, 0, 0]

today = datetime.now().today()
1_day_ago = today - timedelta(days=1)
2_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=2)
3_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=3)


qs = User_activity.objects
if qs.filter(timestamp__gte = 1_day_ago).count():
    has[0] = 1

if qs.filter(timestamp__range= (2_days_ago, 1_day_ago)).count():
    has[1] = 2

if qs.filter(timestamp__range= (3_days_ago, 2_days_ago)).count():
    has[2] = 3

return has
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check whether an object exist you can use the [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) operator:

```
if ( User_activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).exists()):
   has.append(1)  
else :
   has.append(0)
```

Or you could use the len() operator to determine the length of the resulting query. It's zero if no entries exist for the given query:

```
qs_today = User_activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)
if len(qs_today) > 0:
   has.append(1)  
else :
   has.append(0)
```